# How to connect Live Writer to Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, windows-live-writer

I have followed the instructions found [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Blogging-with-LiveWriter) and [here](http://www.simiansblog.com/simian-s-blog/orchard-and-live-writer). Also:

- I am using Orchard Orchard v.1.7.0.0
- I am hosting in a Windows Azure Website
- I have setup Remote Blog Publishing and XmlRpc.
- I have tried the all three domain names that point to the website.
- My actual blog name is http://www.muddlingthru.com/we-re-all-just-muddling-thru

Here is an image of my attempt to add the blog.

[image]

Windows Live Writer says it "was not able to automatically detect your blog settings." So, I try to do it manually as follows.

[image]

Windows Live Writer says, "Invalid Server Response - The response to the blogger.getUsersBlogs method received from the blog server was invalid."

I have already setup Remote Blog Publishing and XmlRpc as follows.

[image]

Is there anything else that I need to do? For instance, when Windows Live Writer asked for the "Remote posting web address for your blog," it has a template like this:

```
http://<hostname>/<mw-script>
```

That I fill in like this:

```
http://www.muddlingthru.com/we-re-all-just-muddling-thru
```

I suspect I might have the incorrect remote posting web address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog account must be the url of your blog, not of a blog post.
It will then detect special metas that indicates the /XmlRpc url that implements MetaWeblog API.

You can also configure it manually choosing Metaweblog provider.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it this week. I did use the URL of the blog, so next I will try using the Metaweblog provider.

Comment: I tried to configure it manually. It did not work. See edit to my question.

Comment: Have you tried to  append XmlRpc at the end of the url? Like http://www.muddlingthru.com/XmlRpc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I disabled the HTML minifier and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

I just installed OpenLive Writer and tried to connect to my Orchard blog and ran into the same problem.

After playing with it a few minutes, I opened the blog page and simply copied and pasted the URL into the Web Address of Your Blog text box.

Bingo, it worked. Only difference, no ending /.